# Infinite struct with JSON and Golang

Tags: json, go

I do not know how to unmarshal this kind of JSON structure with Golang. I get the response from a REST API. The key is dynamic, the nested keys and values are also dynamic..

```
{"key1":{"col1":"Data11","col2":"Data12","col3":"Data13","col4":"Data14"},
 "key2":{"col1":"Data21","col2":"Data22","col3":"Data23","col4":"Data24"},
 "key3":{"col1":"Data31","col2":"Data32","col3":"Data33","col4":"Data34"},
 "key4":{"col1":"Data41","col2":"Data42","col3":"Data43","col4":"Data44"},
 "key5":{"col1":"Data51","col2":"Data52","col3":"Data53","col4":"Data54"},
 "key6":{"col1":"Data61","col2":"Data62","col3":"Data63","col4":"Data64"}}
```

I tried with JsonToStruct and I get this obviously :

```golang
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Key1 struct {
        Col1 string `json:"col1"`
        Col2 string `json:"col2"`
        Col3 string `json:"col3"`
        Col4 string `json:"col4"`
    } `json:"key1"`
    Key2 struct {
        Col1 string `json:"col1"`
        Col2 string `json:"col2"`
        Col3 string `json:"col3"`
        Col4 string `json:"col4"`
    } `json:"key2"`
    Key3 struct {
        Col1 string `json:"col1"`
        Col2 string `json:"col2"`
        Col3 string `json:"col3"`
        Col4 string `json:"col4"`
    } `json:"key3"`
    Key4 struct {
        Col1 string `json:"col1"`
        Col2 string `json:"col2"`
        Col3 string `json:"col3"`
        Col4 string `json:"col4"`
    } `json:"key4"`
    Key5 struct {
        Col1 string `json:"col1"`
        Col2 string `json:"col2"`
        Col3 string `json:"col3"`
        Col4 string `json:"col4"`
    } `json:"key5"`
    Key6 struct {
        Col1 string `json:"col1"`
        Col2 string `json:"col2"`
        Col3 string `json:"col3"`
        Col4 string `json:"col4"`
    } `json:"key6"`
}
```

But I do not know the name of the key that I will get in my response, so that I need a generic unmarshaling. I am stuck.

Comment: Is your JSON data format always looks the same or does it change dynamically (number of fields and field name?)

Comment: @Ehsan.Saradar : Fields name and number of fields will change yes..

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes..

Comment: At what point you have problem. What you did, what is the error. You didn't specify any of these

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma : Tried to edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unmarshal your data into map[string]map[string]string as the following:

```
jsonData:="{\"key1\":{\"col1\":\"Data11\",\"col2\":\"Data12\",\"col3\":\"Data13\",\"col4\":\"Data14\"}, \"key2\":{\"col1\":\"Data21\",\"col2\":\"Data22\",\"col3\":\"Data23\",\"col4\":\"Data24\"}, \"key3\":{\"col1\":\"Data31\",\"col2\":\"Data32\",\"col3\":\"Data33\",\"col4\":\"Data34\"}, \"key4\":{\"col1\":\"Data41\",\"col2\":\"Data42\",\"col3\":\"Data43\",\"col4\":\"Data44\"}, \"key5\":{\"col1\":\"Data51\",\"col2\":\"Data52\",\"col3\":\"Data53\",\"col4\":\"Data54\"}, \"key6\":{\"col1\":\"Data61\",\"col2\":\"Data62\",\"col3\":\"Data63\",\"col4\":\"Data64\"}}"
    var jsonObject map[string]map[string]string
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData),&jsonObject)
    for k:=range jsonObject{
        fmt.Println(k ," has " , len(jsonObject[k]) , " fields")
        for j:=range jsonObject[k]{
            fmt.Println(j , "=",jsonObject[k][j] )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed it